# Simple core animation movement IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is some code for a core animation that can move an image across screen onload. It was working fine but now not so much. If any of you are familiar with core animation, id like to know how to make an image not slide across screen to a fixed position onload like this code below does; but simply have it rotate on its own axis. The effect would look like a rectangle rotating to the right on its own axis continuously like a classic loading animation. Any tips would be helpful. Ant keywords or phrases to point me in the write direction.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    CALayer * layer;
} 

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle   mainBundle]pathForResource:@"flogo@2x"ofType:@"png"]];
    layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)image2.CGImage;
    layer.position = CGPointMake ([self view].bounds.size.width /2, [self view].bounds.size.height /3 );
    layer.bounds= CGRectMake (100,100,1000,1000);
    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer: layer];

    layer = [CALayer layer];
    layer.position = CGPointMake ([self view].bounds.size.width /2, [self view].bounds.size.height   /3 );
    layer.bounds= CGRectMake (100,100,1000,1000);

    CABasicAnimation * moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    moveAnimation.duration = 2;
    moveAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:layer.position.y];
    moveAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:layer.position.y + 600];

    layer.position = CGPointMake(layer.position.x, layer.position.y +100);
    [layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey: @"move1"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[myView animateWithDuration:animations:]` from the UIView class, and for the animations code block, pass some code that changes the transform property of the view's layer to incorporate the rotation.

I don't know much about Core Animation and have no idea if this will work, but figured you wanted all the help you could get. Hope this helps!